# Can/should we delete wordpress cron jobs with no action?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cron

I find myself during a website creation where I try several plugins and delete them afterwards. However, some plugins do not clean their cron jobs and are left to be executed with no action.

My question is this:
Should we clean up/delete leftover crons with no action?
If we should, what is the best way to do it? Is manual the only way to go (ex. WP Crontrol plugin)?
Bonus: If we should not, why not?

It would be handy to have a small function to take with me and add it to child themes. I am thinking an action during post/page save like:

```
add_action('save_post', 'clean_empty_crons');
```

Comment: WordPress has a function `wp_unschedule_event` for this purpose. They encourage developers to remove their crons during deactivation, however, many developers don't. I am also interested in seeing the time complexity of this.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/#unscheduling-tasks